# SQL Server 2008 Password Hashing with a salt

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. I can create a hashed password with a salt. Is there a way to reverse hash password with salt if the salt is known? If yes, how?

Comment: It depends on hashing algoriths you've used for creating hashed password. All commonly used cryptohash functions are one-way, so you can't directly get password from hash even if salt is known.

Comment: Usually no unless you are using an obsolete hashing algorithm that can be reversed without much effort. The point of using hash + salt to store passwords is to make "encryption" one way.

Comment: Thank you both for your prompt response. I am using SHA1. And my idea was to have a desktop application distributed, but when a client gets it, when he runs it, it should read the SN of a CPU and add a salt to it then get the combination hashed. And this should be sent to me. One receiving, I wanted to reverse it and get the SN of that MB update it on the table and then generate a key and send it to client for activation. That way I would have made it harder for the client to use it on any other computer or even to give it to someone else.

Comment: You should use [PKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) instead of just hashing the information. Encrypt with public key, decrypt with private key known only to you.

Comment: Thank you. I will do just that.